# Trac hotcopy backup fails due to MySql login failure

Tags: mysql, trac

I'm trying to move a trac 1.0 instance from one machine to another. I used the Trac Backup and Restore Process described here, which uses the hotcopy command.

http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBackup

I then created a fresh MySql database, with a new user for trac, assigned appropriate permissions, and then ran the tracadmin initenv command to create the new trac environment. I deployed this using tracd, and it seemed to work fine.

When I attempt to replace this fresh environment with the contents of the hotcopy backup, I get the following error when I try to connect to the server....

Am I missing some step? I've changed MySql permissions to make sure they match the password and username that I passed to trac in the database string. Is it possible that this was overwritten when I copied the new environment over and that trac is using the wrong password to connect to the MySql?

Any help is much appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/api.py", line 502, in send_error
    data, 'text/html')
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/chrome.py", line 955, in render_template
    message = req.session.pop('chrome.%s.%d' % (type_, i))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/api.py", line 304, in __getattr__
    value = self.callbacks[name](self)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/main.py", line 268, in _get_session
    return Session(self.env, req)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/session.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.get_session(sid)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/session.py", line 229, in get_session
    super(Session, self).get_session(sid, authenticated)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/session.py", line 76, in get_session
    with self.env.db_query as db:
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/db/api.py", line 165, in __enter__
    db = DatabaseManager(self.env).get_connection(readonly=True)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/db/api.py", line 250, in get_connection
    db = self._cnx_pool.get_cnx(self.timeout or None)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/db/pool.py", line 213, in get_cnx
    return _backend.get_cnx(self._connector, self._kwargs, timeout)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/db/pool.py", line 134, in get_cnx
    raise TimeoutError(errmsg)
TimeoutError: Unable to get database connection within 0 seconds. (OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'trac_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I never could get those "hotcopy" instructions to work.  They seem like they were written with sqlite in mind and not MySQL.  When I migrated my Trac instance to a new server, I had to do the following to get my database working:

```
# On old server
$ mysqldump -u admin -padmin_password trac >backup.sql

# On new server
$ mysql -u admin -padmin_password
mysql> CREATE DATABASE trac DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
mysql> GRANT ALL ON trac.* TO trac_account@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'topsecret';
mysql> exit
$ mysql -u admin -padmin_password trac <backup.sql
```

Replace "trac_account" and "topsecret" with the username and password that Trac will use.  After that, I was able to get Trac up and running.  Essentially, forget that Trac was involved and treat the whole thing like a normal database backup and restore operation.  As far as the rest of Trac goes, I just created a new Trac instance on the new server using the imported database and then copied over files from the old server as needed (config files, attachments, custom templates, etc).

Note: In case it's relevant, my old and new installations used the same MySQL database credentials for Trac.  If you're changing credentials as part of the move, YMMV.

Comment: `hotcopy` only creates the backup, it won't restore the database dump on PostgreSQL or MySQL. You should find the MySQL database dump in the archive, but I've never confirmed this on MySQL. The database must be manually restored. The command has been documented for [PostgreSQL](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBackup#RestoringaBackup). Feel free to add to the documentation for MySQL.